# What causes a point cloud image distort like this?

Tags: opencv, 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a Time-of-Flight sensor using IR as illumination.

I use PCL(Point Cloud Library) to get point cloud data from that sensor.

The result really confused me.

[image: That thing is my wallet]

The object is nearly flat as a plane, it doesn't look like what I expected(or any other point cloud image you can google),

and if you look right from the side, there is a big curve.

[image: The red line]

also look from the top

[image: The red line]

I've search this issue for a long time.

The top reason to cause this I guess is "lens distortion".

However, as I implemented the algorithm in Opencv that it claims to solve lens distortion, the result still look the same.

There are still other reasons I presume like pixel offset, gradient offset...etc, but I don't know how to deal with them.

I really need help since I never study Optics, 3D, and I only googled "pinhole camera" to seek knowledge for just 1 week(I know intrinsic, extrinsic parameters).

I will be very appreciated of getting any clue about what to do next.

Comment: There are many reasons that can cause that behavior, I'd need more information to help you, for example a code snapshot or a description of the procedure you're using to process data from the Kinect and plot them

Comment: What sensor is this? Have you considered that it may return distances from optical center rather than distances along optical axis? (I had this issue with PMD Camboard nano, you may have a look at [this passage](https://github.com/taketwo/pmd_camboard_nano#distance-vs-depth-images) and corresponding code.)

Comment: @taketwo What 's the difference between "return distances from optical center" and "distances along optical axis"? If this is a issue of Optics, maybe some keywords can let me dig into it, thx.

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh Actually it's the same sensor used on SoftKinetics DS325, and I am using DepthSense SDK to retrieve data, the data then be sent to PCL forming a .pcd file and can be visualize. The distortion calibration procedure was done before the data was sent to PCL.

Comment: In [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model#/media/File:Pinhole2.svg) `OP` is distance from optical center, and `x3` is distance along optical axis. Obviously, they are related by cosine of the angle between the axis and the vector to the scene point. That means that for the points that are close to the axis the distances are the same, whereas for the further away points the `OP` distance is larger, hence observed distortion.

Comment: By the way, you can use my PCL grabber for DepthSense cameras. It's not yet included in mainstream PCL, but for the time being you can get it from a [standalone repository](https://github.com/taketwo/ds).

Comment: did you find your solution yet  ?